# AngularJs Event after loading model data in view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am stuck with a problem, I have one html node containing content that is a view of a controller, and I am hitting an api to fetch data from server as model of that particular view in html.

After that I need to perform some javascript changes on DOM of loaded content.

So basically I want to know the **event** which **triggers after binding the model value on page**?

Comment: question is not clear. add some code or more details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `$viewContentLoaded` event

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {
    // manipulate DOM
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a function that waits till the content is loaded

```
function afterLoad() {
    if( $(MYELEMENT).text!='' ) //jQuery to check if the content is empty
    {
        //Code here
    }
    else
    {
        setTimeout(afterLoad(), 10);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look at ng-watch it fires when a model is updated

```
$scope.$watch("theModel", function(newValue, oldValue){
    // do something with newValue!
});
```

Comment: I have tried it but, this is checking for model value not on loading the content in view. I need to fire the event after the model value is  loaded.

Comment: ok, you need to think in Angular. With Angular, you tend not to perform DOM manipulation based on data. Instead you create Views or Templates and bind them to a model with a controller. It may take a bit of getting used to, but once you get it - you will see the benefits.